# Ignore null values when sorting by array in MongoDB

Tags: mongodb, sorting

I have MongoDB collection `items` with following documents:

```
{ "values" : [1, 2] }
{ "values" : [5, null] }
{ "values" : [-5, null] }
```

Is there any way to sort this collection by `values` property without `null` values? My current query is:

```
db.items.aggregate([{"$sort": {"values": 1}}])
```

with this result:

```
{ "values" : [5, null] }
{ "values" : [-5, null] }
{ "values" : [1, 2] }
```

First values are `[5, null]` and `[-5, null]` because `null` is smallest value in collection. However, I would like to ignore null values and sort by numbers only, so:

```
{ "values" : [-5, null] }
{ "values" : [1, 2] }
{ "values" : [5, null] }
```

When there is no number (both values are `null`), document should be last in result.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Other alternatives:

**Solution 1:** In case preservation of all `null` values[] or `null` fields in the array itself is not necessary.

Filter out the **not null** elements using [`$filter`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/filter/), the ( all `null` elements) array would be empty, filter that out from documents using [`$match`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/match/) then [`$sort`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/sort/#sort-operator-and-performance) on `values`.

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    $project: {
      values: {
        $filter: {
          input: "$values",
          as: "d",
          cond: {
            $ne: [
              "$$d",
              null
            ]
          }
        }
      }
    }
  },
  {
    $match: {
      "values": {
        $ne: []
      }
    }
  },
  {
    "$sort": {
      "values": 1
    }
  }
]);
```

[Play Link](https://mongoplayground.net/p/nq796zZyPqU)

**Solution 2:** Not a great approach IMO. But gets the job done and preserves the documents and `null` values as it is.

First convert `null` values to `"null"` strings for the `$sort` order to work based on field type. Convert back the `"null"` strings to `null` using [`$map`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/map/)

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    $project: {
      values: {
        $map: {
          input: "$values",
          as: "d",
          in: {
            $cond: {
              if: {
                $eq: [
                  "$$d",
                  null
                ]
              },
              then: "null",
              else: "$$d"
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  },
  {
    "$sort": {
      "values": 1
    }
  },
  {
    $project: {
      values: {
        $map: {
          input: "$values",
          as: "d",
          in: {
            $cond: {
              if: {
                $eq: [
                  "$$d",
                  "null"
                ]
              },
              then: null,
              else: "$$d"
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
]);
```

[Play Link](https://mongoplayground.net/p/t6v-xoWqDCA)

Answer (score 2):

You can try this,

- `$addFields` to create `values_clone` of `values` using `$map`, replace `null` to string `"null"`, because when we sort it will sort last

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    $addFields: {
      values_clone: {
        $map: {
          input: "$values",
          as: "v",
          in: {
            $cond: {
              if: { $eq: ["$$v", null] },
              then: "null",
              else: "$$v"
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  },
```

- `$sort` by `values_clone` ascending order

```
  { $sort: { values_clone: 1 } },
```

- `$project` to hide `values_clone`

```
  { $project: { values_clone: 0 } }
])
```

[Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/o26d3OdKjyQ)

Comment: A fine solution as well (liked the approach of `values_clone` as tag along). But this also loses the document if both elements of `values` are `[null, null]`.

Comment: @ambianBeing, thanks, yes i realize that will do some solution for that, you have too nice solutions

Answer (score 1):

You can do using the below stages

[play](https://mongoplayground.net/p/P_bKB-ZRsv2)

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    $unwind: "$values" //unwind them to skip null values
  },
  {
    $match: {
      "values": { //skip null values
        $ne: null
      }
    }
  },
  {
    "$sort": { //sorting pipeline
      "values": 1
    }
  },
  {
    $group: { //regrouping them
      "_id": "$_id",
      "values": {
        $push: "$values"
      }
    }
  }
])
```

If you want to ignore complete array even if one value is null, you can skip `unwind` and `group` stages.